# Manually trigger receive event for jquery-ui sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr8QD/) of my code so far.

When you drag into the open space, an empty group will be created. I may be going about this the wrong way, but I would like the item that is dragged to the new group to be populated into the list. Is there a way to call the receive event from the jquery-ui sortables widget to achieve this.

Alternately, should I prepopulate the group that is being added with the item un the drop method of the droppable item

```
drop: function (event, ui){
    $(element).append($(ui.helper).clone());
}
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually trigger a sortable event by using jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event like so:

`$('#sortable-name').trigger('sortreceive');`

I do think your code looks a bit strange, but that is perhaps because I have never seen someone use jQuery UI in a widget format.

Josh

Comment: thanks for the straightforward answer, not the method I used, but it's been so long, I don't remember how I got past this